# Solving a recurrence relation involving binomial coefficients

Tags: co.combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, recurrences

This question originates from a graph neural network architecture (see [1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.11136)) in which an edge-labelled graph $G=(V,E,\eta)$  of size $|V|=n$ with $\eta:E\to \mathbb{R}^{s_0}$ is represented as a "tensor'' $\mathbf{A}_G^{(0)}\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n\times s_0}$, and in which for round $t>0$, a new tensor $\mathbf{A}_G^{(t)}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n\times s_t}$ is defined in terms of $\mathbf{A}_G^{(t-1)}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n\times s_{t-1}}$. The dimension $s_t$ is defined as ${n + s_{t-1}-1 \choose s_{t-1}-1}$ for $t>0$.

**Question:** Given $n$ and $a_0$ in $\mathbb{N}$, define $a_t:={n+a_{t-1}\choose a_{t-1}}$ for $t>0$. Is there an explicit formulation of $a_t$ in terms of $n$, $a_0$ and $t$? In other words, how to "solve" such a recurrence relation? What can one say about $a_t$ when $t$ is large?

Answer (score 1):

A quick remark rather than answer is that
$$
a_t={\rm dim}_{\mathbb{C}}\{\ S^n(S^n(\cdots S^n(\mathbb{C}^{a_0})\cdots))\ \}
$$
where you iterate taking the $n$-th symmetric power $t$ times.

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed an expression for $a_t$ in terms of $n$, $a_0$ and $t$ but I was aiming for a more explicit function. Nice connection though.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the recursion by using n rather than a_{t-1} for the bottom coefficient.  Now you have an explicit formula as an iterated polynomial (as in the other answer) and  a_t grows like a_0^(tn).

Gerhard "But Do Mind The Coefficients" Paseman, 2020.06.05.

Comment: Indeed, the nth root of the coefficient will come from Stirling's approximation for factorial, and so  a_t will look like ((ea_0)/n)^(tn). Gerhard "Don't Need No Lower Powers" Paseman, 2020.06.05.

Comment: Thanks, I see that $a_t$ could be alternatively defined as ${n+a_{t-1} \choose n}$ but when writing this as a polynomial, the coefficients also seem to depend on $n$?

Comment: Yes. The constant coefficient is 1, and the rest depend on n, including the first which is 1/n! . Gerhard "Leaves The Rest To You" Paseman, 2020.06.05.